# Bubble map using google api

Tags: google-maps

i want to draw a bubble map using google api as given in the link

http://www.improving-visualisation.org/vis/id=334

Is there any tutorial which will be helpful to plot similat type of map.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for somethign like markerclusterer?

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/markerclusterer-solution-to-too-many.html